# siunitx fails to include group separator

Tags: tables, formatting, siunitx

I am using the siunitx package to format a table and I cannot make it include commas to separate thousands. I also want the figures to align, which is working so far with my code. I have tried moving the group-separator option around and placing it after sisetup, but that did not help either.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}
\captionsetup[table]{font=large}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage[group-separator = {,},
            group-four-digits]{siunitx} % centering in tables
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l *{2}{S[table-format=4.3]} S[table-format=4.0]} \toprule \toprule
                    &\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Everyone}}\\
                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{{Mean}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{{Std.Dev.}}&\multicolumn{1}{l}{{Obs}}\\
\midrule
Some label       &       0.123&       0.123&        9999\\
Some label       &       0.123&       0.123&        9999\\
Some label          &       0.123&       0.123&        9999\\
Some label abc&       0.123&       0.123&        9999\\
Some label abc&    1234.123&    1234.123&        9999\\
Some label abc&    1234.123&    1234.123&         999\\
Some label abc&     123.123&     316.123&         999\\
\bottomrule \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

My table currently looks as in the picture below.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. This seems to be due to some weird option processing / brace stripping. `group-separator = {{,}}` does what you want, although I'm not sure one should *have* to do that.

Comment: Thank you @frougon! Your suggestion works well. I am not sure what you mean with the brace stripping part. I have tried cleaning the code to the very minimum and the issue was still there. Where do you think the issue comes from?

Comment: The way options are parsed in the `\usepackage[...]{siunitx}` call appears to remove your comma for whatever reason (attempting to process the value as a comma-separated list?). If you use `\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{group-separator = {,}, group-four-digits}`, there is no such problem.

Comment: That's right, @frougon, including the sisetup the way you suggest also fixes the problem. I had tried using sisetup before but likely I made some other mistake in the code. Many thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad to help. I believe I've read that option processing by `\usepackage` is imperfect, and I guess this can't really be changed without risking to break a lot of packages. Using `\sisetup` seems to me to be the cleanest way to solve the problem (in the absence of a fix for `\usepackage[...]{siunitx}` option processing).

Answer (score 2):

The only way I've managed to have the Spanish style 1234.12345 →  1.234,12345 is with:

```
[group-separator= \text{.}]
```

after

```
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[group-separator= \text{.}]{siunitx}
```

so

```
\num{12345.6789}
```

produces:

[image]

So, for the complete text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{group-separator= \text{.},
         group-minimum-digits = 4,
         group-digits = integer}

\begin{document}
Prueba: \num{12345.6789}
\[
    \frac{\text{6500111.1234}}{\num{6500111.1234}}
\]
\[
    \sen\alpha = \frac{630,3}{\num{630,3}}\\
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice first answer! Could you edit after your image the (minimal) code to reproduce your image please? As in, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` just so people in the future can copy and paste your code to see the result so it helps future people `:)`

Comment: The OP wants a comma to separate thousands and a decimal point.

Answer (score 1):

With a current version of `siunitx` there is no longer `group-four-digits` (although `group-four-digits=true` still works).

With an older TeX distribution (here TeX Live 2020),

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{siunitx} % centering in tables

\captionsetup[table]{font=large}

\sisetup{
  group-separator = {,},
  group-four-digits,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering

\caption{A caption}

\begin{tabular}{l *{2}{S[table-format=4.3]} S[table-format=4.0]}
\toprule
  &\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Everyone}}\\
  &\multicolumn{1}{c}{{Mean}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{{Std.\ Dev.}}&\multicolumn{1}{l}{{Obs}}\\
\midrule
Some label     &       0.123&       0.123&        9999\\
Some label     &       0.123&       0.123&        9999\\
Some label     &       0.123&       0.123&        9999\\
Some label abc &       0.123&       0.123&        9999\\
Some label abc &    1234.123&    1234.123&        9999\\
Some label abc &    1234.123&    1234.123&         999\\
Some label abc &     123.123&     316.123&         999\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Using `\sisetup` is recommended over passing options when the package is loaded.

With a current TeX distribution

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{siunitx} % centering in tables

\captionsetup[table]{font=large}

\sisetup{
  group-separator = {,},
  group-minimum-digits=4,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering

\caption{A caption}

\begin{tabular}{l *{2}{S[table-format=4.3]} S[table-format=4.0]}
\toprule
  &\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Everyone}}\\
  &\multicolumn{1}{c}{{Mean}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{{Std.\ Dev.}}&\multicolumn{1}{l}{{Obs}}\\
\midrule
Some label     &       0.123&       0.123&        9999\\
Some label     &       0.123&       0.123&        9999\\
Some label     &       0.123&       0.123&        9999\\
Some label abc &       0.123&       0.123&        9999\\
Some label abc &    1234.123&    1234.123&        9999\\
Some label abc &    1234.123&    1234.123&         999\\
Some label abc &     123.123&     316.123&         999\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I probably need to adjust the compatible code a tad